# Making my JObjects only change color on mouse press?

Tags: java, mouseevent

I have an ArrayList of an object, name of the ArrayList is siteArray. I created called ResearchSites.  I can click anywhere in the frame to create them.

Once they exist, I need to be able to click them again and have the color change to blue.

How would I go about this? I am attempting to do it in my MousePressed method, which is pasted below.

```
public void mousePressed( MouseEvent me )
{
    ResearchSite newSite = new ResearchSite(getParent().getMousePosition());
    this.add( newSite );
    siteArray.add( newSite );
    newSite.setDraggable( true );
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add a property to the research site object: pressed which is boolean and false in default.

You can do something like this:

1. check if pressed is false or true.
2. false: change to true and display frame
3. true: change color to blue in the repaint method

in the paint method:

1. check if pressed or not
2. false: add the frame
3. true: change color to blue

Comment: This might work. I'll give it a go! Every time I press on the frame, a red one needs to appear. When I click on it after it appears, it needs to turn blue. Will this work if I make a boolean for the entire press?

Comment: What do you mean by the entire press?

Comment: I'm not sure it's working, because it all needs to be done in the mousePressed method. How would I go about that?